# Grep count of processes running more than x minutes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

My goal is to grep for a count of processes older than 'x' minutes in bash.

So far, I can grep for all the process execution times:

`ps -eo etime,cmd | grep mysuperspecialprocess.sh | grep -Ev 'grep' | awk '{print $1}'`

I pipe a `wc -l` to get a count at the end.

How can I grep or loop through the result to restrict it to processes older than a certain number of minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this tested version a try.

It searches a specified running process, and count all occurences which has an associated elapsed time greater than a specified number of seconds.

Set parameters' values first and run it.

```
$ cat ./script.sh 
#!/bin/bash --

process_name=mysuperspecialprocess.sh

elapsed_time_seconds=600

ps -eo etimes,cmd | fgrep "${process_name}" | fgrep -v fgrep | ( count=0 ; while read etimes cmd ; do \
  if [ $etimes -gt $elapsed_time_seconds ] ;\
  then \
    count=$((count+1)) ;\
  fi ;\
done ; echo $count )
```

**etimes** instructs **ps** to display seconds.

Comment: the main issues reported by **shellcheck** fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

starting with the etime field you can do something similar to this, ignores seconds.

```
$ awk 'NR>1{n=split($1,a,":");            # split the field
            if(n==2) mins=a[1]+0;         # if hours not present set mins
            else {d=split(a[1],h,"-");    # check for days
                  hours=(d==2?h[1]*24+h[2]:h[1]);   # incorporate days in hours
                  mins=hours*60+a[2]}      # compute mins
            print $1, mins}' etimes

00:04 0
02:30:44 150
01:03:11 63
1-01:01:01 1501
3-00:02:00 4322
```