# Killing a process that has been running for more than x minutes

Tags: python, bash, shell

I know that there have been many answers to this question but here is something I want to do:

ps auxww | grep python

This will give me all the python processes. Now, I want to get all the python processes running for more than 5 mins and kill them.

Somehow for the answers in examples like below, etimes doesnt work for me. Could be because my Linux is 5.3:

[Grep count of processes running more than x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873018/grep-count-of-processes-running-more-than-x-minutes)

Can someone please help.

Comment: Will `timeout` when calling the python scripts in the first place suit your needs?

Comment: Not quite, because these processes are getting forked on the fly which I dont have a control over. So the only thing I can do is start something every 10 mins to check and see if something has been running for 5 mins or so and if so, then kill it!

Comment: fwiw, your linux kernel is not version 5.3; we're on 4.18 at the latest. bash 5.0 is in alpha. `cat /etc/*release` should be able to tell you more about what you're running, as should `bash --version`

Comment: @jeremysprofile I am using Redhat Server 5.3. Anyways, that's not what I am stuck at. Would you be able to help me with the original question I had?

Comment: so you're saying that `ps -eo etimes,cmd | grep python` doesn't output the seconds each python process has been running and the name of the cmd? What does it output?

Comment: I get the below error:
    `ERROR: Unknown user-defined format specifier "etimes".`

Comment: then your next best bet will be going through `man ps` and searching for `time`. There are other time options, but none are as easy to work with. There is `bsdstart`, `lstart`, `etime` (not plural), `start_time`, etc. You'll probably have to compare these to the current time to check how long it's been since the process started, and go from there.

Comment: okay. Thank you!